# Swift SDWebImage in a closure block

Tags: swift, sdwebimage

I am attempting to use SDWebImage in a closure block after fetching userInfo from Firebase. However, doing so will result in the images and cell labels to blink as I scroll the tableView when the cells are attempting to redraw themselves.

```
let expiredConversationsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "expiredConversationsCell", for: indexPath) as! ExpiredConversationsTableViewCell

let conversation = allConversations[0][indexPath.row]
guard let recipientID = conversation.recipientID else {return UITableViewCell()}

FirebaseClient.shared.getUserInfo(recipientID, { (results, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } else if let results = results {
        let username = results["username"] as! String
        let profileImageUrl = results["profileImageUrl"] as! String

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            expiredConversationsCell.profileImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: profileImageUrl), completed: nil)
            expiredConversationsCell.recipientNameLabel.text = username
        }
    }
})

return expiredConversationsCell
```

Is there a way to implement SDWebImages under such circumstances? Any advice would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What is that you want to achieve? You want the images/ labels to blink? what kind of problem are you facing?

Comment: Note that you don't have to write `sd_setImage()` in `DispatchQueue.main.async{}`.

Comment: @AkshanshThakur I do not want the images/labels to blink, which they are right now. The images/labels will blink and flicker as I scroll up and down the tableView.

Comment: @Larme Noted, but I have also tried placing it outside. It makes no difference